# making oracle merge insert or update faster

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am running through a list one by one and merging the data from that list based on a long list of conditions into a different table.

The merge does an insert when not matched, update when matched. I find this merge to be taking a lot of time.

It takes me 10seconds to run through a list of 200 records which seems excessive. Is there a way to make this merge faster please? Thank You

```
stmt := 'MERGE INTO dash_'||domain_name||'_rag TARGETd USING (SELECT '||''''||ms||''''||' AS JNDI, '||''''||domain_name||''''||' AS DOMAIN, ''Y'' AS TARGET, '||''''||jndi_type||''''||' AS JNDI_TYPE, '||''''||jndi_s||''''||' AS MS2_D1, '||''''||RAGr||''''||' AS MS2_D1R, '||'SYSDATE AS TS FROM DUAL) SOURCE ON (SOURCE.JNDI=TARGETd.JNDI) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (JNDI, DOMAIN, TARGET, JNDI_TYPE,MS2_D1, MS2_D1R, TS) VALUES(SOURCE.JNDI, SOURCE.DOMAIN, SOURCE.TARGET, SOURCE.JNDI_TYPE,SOURCE.MS2_D1, SOURCE.MS2_D1R, SOURCE.TS)WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TARGETd.TARGET = SOURCE.TARGET, TARGETd.MS2_D1=SOURCE.MS2_D1, TARGETd.MS2_D1R=SOURCE.MS2_D1R, TARGETd.TS=SOURCE.TS';

      execute immediate stmt;
```

Comment: Why are you concatenating the variable values like `ms` etc. each time, instead of using bind variables?

Comment: Why are you using procedural code (and "merging" one row at a time) in the first place? The best optimization - if it is possible, and you haven't provided enough information to know that - is to rewrite everything in plain SQL and run it all in the database, without switching contexts back and forth between SQL and PL/SQL.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for your suggestion Alex. I replaced the concatenation with bind variables and the speeds improved remarkably. I am novice programmer, hadn't realized this effect. Cheers!